# How do I install AMD Mobility Radeon 4250 drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

I don't know how to install them. I tried to install some drivers but when it rebooted I got a black screen. I had to boot into windows and wipe ubuntu/re-install all over again. Can someone give me a link to drivers that work.

Comment: Probably the open-source drivers would do what you want. Any reason for installing the proprietary drivers?

Comment: Gallium 0.4 seems quite slow e.g. with the Dash and task switcher.